# Things to consider before building a third party application to make it compatible with USD

Tags: crm, unified-service-desk

I am working for a client and they are creating an application that they want to host on Unified Service Desk.

As you all know that Unified Service Desk's new version 4.1 has been released earlier. I read a related article on Microsoft as well that things to keep in mind when you check the existing Unified Service Desk Version.

But the thing I want to know here is on what technologies should they built there third party applications are there any nitty gritties that

Are there any points that should be considered so that we can make an application compatible and workable inside Unified Service Desk,

I want to know like,

1. What platform should they consider
2. What Language should they consider
3. And any other specific details that we keep in mind before
   creating the application

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can depend on their internal dev skillset and whether they want the application to be accessible outside of USD.  For web apps, they should consider whether they are targeting a browser that will have long-term support from Microsoft.  We're starting to see Chrome support, and will eventually see Edge support also.  IE will eventually go away, but it's not clear when.  If no one needs the application outside of USD, then a C#/XAML compiled control would naturally provide reliability and speed above and beyond any web app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but they are creating Windows Application so I want to know what details should be kept in mind before making windows application